# How to run some function and print that the function is active while it is

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to run some function and print that the function is active at the time it runs, but only the function runs and the printing isn't. Why?

I'm using the `threading` library in Python.

```
print("Waiting for key...")
keyboard_listening = Thread(target=key_pressed())  # key_pressed has while loop that
                                                   # prints every 1 second
info = Thread(target=print("After thread"))

keyboard_listening.start()  # Running
info.start()  # Not running
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `Thread` a callable, not the result of the function after you call it. This is the difference between `key_pressed()` and `key_pressed`.

So, you want something like

```py
print("Waiting for key...")
keyboard_listening = Thread(target=key_pressed)

info = Thread(target=lambda: print("After thread"))

keyboard_listening.start()
info.start()
```

where `lambda` is used to create a one-line function.